# Mulesoft server configure/access web server

Tags: apache, webserver, mule

A beginner in Mule and Server deployment, so please help. I have my local apache http web server running and configured the web server settings in a third party application. And the third party application's web service POST HTTP data to web server which I can access in PHP file and view the data.

How to simulate the same in Mule? Is it possible to configure Mule Server as web server in that application? If not can I access the data available in apache web server through any connectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mule comes with an HTTP Connector, so yes it can receive HTTP POST requests.

Reference: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/HTTP+Connector

Comment: @maliniJ  Pls accept the answer if it works .. pls don't leave answer unaccepted

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Using HTTP connector you can send POST request to the server .
you also wont have to configure the server properties just the port at which you'll access your application.

```
<flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="Server_Address_e.g._localhost" port="Enter_Port_Here" path="Enter_your_path_here" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```